# JWT token removed from header on reload. How to fix it?

Tags: mysql, node.js, authentication, vuejs2, bearer-token

I'm trying to setup a Vue2js app with node.js/express, using JWT authentication.

When signing in token is generated (with bearer) and stored in the client-side (Vuex) successfully.

**When reload token somehow dissapers from header and I don't know why?**
So when calling **fetchAccountFromToken** function from helpers/token.js I have below error on the server side:
"*TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined*"

helpers/token.js

```
export function fetchAccountFromToken(token) {
    return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(token.split('.')[1], 'base64').toString('utf-8'))['user']
}
```

And I have this code in server.js

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body == null) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid login. Please try again' })
  } else {
    const userService = new UserService()
    const token = await userService.loginUser({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    })

    console.log(token)

    if (token) {
      res.json({ token })
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid login. Please try again' })
    }
  }
})
```

UserService.js

```
export default class UserService {
  async loginUser(loginUserRequest) {
    const { email, password } = loginUserRequest
    
    const userRepository = new UserRepository()
    const userDto = await userRepository.getUserByEmail(email)

    if (userDto.email === email && userDto.password === password) {
      let user = {
        id: userDto.id,
        email: userDto.email,
        firstName: userDto.firstName,
        lastName: userDto.lastName,
        role: userDto.role
      }

      return jwt.sign({ user }, 'the_secret_key') //secret key je za validacijo tokena
    }

    return null
    // return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid login. Please try again.'}) // NEEDS to send error if credentials don't match !!!! //
  }
```

UserRepository.js

```
export default class UserRepository {
  async getUserByEmail(email) {
    let dbContext = new DbContext()

    try {
      const query = 'SELECT id, email, password, firstName, lastName, role FROM accounts WHERE email = ?'
      const users = await dbContext.query(query, [email])

      return users[0]
    } finally {
      dbContext.close()
    }
  }
```

And I have this code in the VueX store module user.js:

```
export const state = {
  user: null
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_USER_DATA(state, data) {
    console.log('logging in with data data:', data)
    let { token } = data
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)

    let tokenPayloadJson = atob(token.split('.')[1])
    let tokenPayload = JSON.parse(tokenPayloadJson)

    let user = tokenPayload.user
    state.user = user

    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))

    console.log('called set user data')

    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${data.token}`
  },
  CLEAR_USER_DATA() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token')
    localStorage.removeItem('user')
    location.reload()
  }
}
export const actions = {
   login({ commit }, credentials) {
    return axios
      .post('//localhost:3000/login', credentials)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        commit('SET_USER_DATA', data)
      })
  },
  fetchUser(id) {
    return AccountService.getUser(id)
      .then(response => {
        return response.data
      })
  },  
  logout({ commit }) {
    commit('CLEAR_USER_DATA')
  }
}
export const getters = {
  loggedIn(state) {
    return !!state.user
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you omitted a crucial component here, I do not see fetchAccountFromToken function called anywhere in your code posted here.

Comment: This is unrelated comment to your current question, It seems that your logout function is simply erasing token from the client side, that's a big "no no". The correct method would be to invalidate the token on a server-side. Why ? Imagine a user is hacked or the token is stolen, without server invalidation after user logs out, the token is still valid, attacker has access. I do not see also you setting a expiration date on your tokens, which means token is valid forever, another big no no.

Comment: Finally, I think you just attach header to axios only on login function, meaning if your reload the app and not login again, the header is not attached. I would suggest using axios interceptor to try and retrieve the token from localStorge on each request and attach headers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see storing the token to VueX, just saving it to localStorage. Additionally I don't see how you are reading it from it (neither localStorage nor VueX store). You can load it from localStorage when initializing the store like this:

```
export const state = {
  user: localStorage.getItem('user'),
  token: localStorage.getItem('token')
}
```